# Squid 5.2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS keeps crashing

Tags: squid

I am running Squid 5.2 installed using `apt` on Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy LTS. This is in a virtual KVM machine with 75GB drive and 6GB of RAM and dual-core AMD Epyc. This build is running on a Synology NAS DS-1821+ on there newer DSM 7.1 OS. The problem I am having is Squid crashing with fatal errors. It works great for a random amount of time, then dies. Here are a sampling of the log errors:

```
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master291
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master57
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master57
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master54
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master59
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012 exception location: tunnel.cc(1300) noteDestinationsEnd#012 current master transaction: master4154
assertion failed: tunnel.cc:1010: "!client.dirty"#012 current master transaction: master83
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as googling these error messages only bring up scenarios that do not seem applicable to my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bug, discussed [here](https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5055#c5).
You could try installing a more recent version of Squid, from this ppa, for example:
[https://launchpad.net/~kgeorgiy/+archive/ubuntu/squid-ssl](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekgeorgiy/+archive/ubuntu/squid-ssl)

You could also try compiling the latest version, as indicated [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#KnowledgeBase.2FUbuntu.Compile_on_A_basic_Ubuntu_Server), on the application's website.